# Asp.Net MVC 5 / angular 2 routing

Tags: typescript, angular, asp.net-mvc-5, angular2-routing

I already developed mvc application and now I am converting it to angluar 2 SPA I have some Issues with Routing mechanism of mvc and with angular because it render mvc routing instead of angular but angular works fine also. How I make my MVc app as SPA What changing will I do to make it SPA?

Comment: You need a controller that renders your angular templates as Partial views.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [Angular 2 and ASP.NET MVC 4 routing are not working together](//stackoverflow.com/a/42408722)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 and ASP.NET MVC 4 routing are not working together](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40831923/angular-2-and-asp-net-mvc-4-routing-are-not-working-together)